# Is there a way to make all pages in a Flask app show the same content?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a Flask app and I wanted to add a custom maintenance mode page controlled using a variable. Is there a way I can do this besides creating if-then statements checking if the variable is true: E.g. what I would do:

```py
@app.route("/mypage")
def mypage():
  if (maintenance_mode == 1):
      return render_template("maintenance.html")
  return "response"
```

I'd like to do this without using an if-then statement and preferably just use 1 `@app.route`.

Comment: Why is having an if-statement not a satisfactory solution? You're trying to do conditional logic, which is exactly what it's meant for.

Comment: My site has something like 50 separate pages so doing that would take a long time and not be very efficient.

Comment: I could but I'd prefer not to and it would be nice to know for future reference.

Comment: It would not be noticeable performance wise. But does that mean you have 50 separate maintenance pages as well? Or is it just 1 and every route should now redirect to that one?

Comment: I don't have 50 separate maintenance pages, but I DO have 50 total pages that all need to be redirected.

Comment: So you're trying to make every url to redirect to the maintenance page? How come? It seems a bit odd. Why don't you have an admin page instead? What is it you're trying to solve?

You might be able to hook into the router logic and override the dispatching, but I'm not sure how to do that in Flask

Comment: This has to do with blueprints but I'd imagine similar is possible without it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49785019/6486738. This also seem to contain some useful information: https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-routes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not even need flask for this and can control it on other levels, but for flask [here](https://gist.github.com/DazWorrall/3180841) are good examples to do so.

It is suggested to add `@app.before_request` and check maintenance flag. (`@app.before_request` will be called before all request, so you do not need to do maintenance check for all 50 routes).

```
@app.before_request
def check_under_maintenance():
    if maintenance_mode == 1:  #this flag can be anything, read from file,db or anything
        abort(503) 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "This is Admiral Ackbar, over"

@app.errorhandler(503)
def error_503(error):
    return render_template("maintenance.html")
```